# Linux service returns (code=exited, status=2)

Tags: linux, go, web-services

I have created a Golang web app and built as an executable. The executable is running well when executed as ./main (main is the name of the executable) from its subdirectory.

I'm trying to create it as a service. I have a file goservice.service

```
[Unit]
Description=goservice

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s
ExecStart=/home/nshankar/go/eperssona/main

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I see the status of the service, I get following response -

```
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/goservice.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-10-28 10:47:54 UTC; 498ms ago
    Process: 13286 ExecStart=/home/nshankar/go/eperssona/main (code=exited, status=2)
   Main PID: 13286 (code=exited, status=2)
        CPU: 4ms
```

The service is listening on port 9002.

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Your program is ending with exit code 2 directly after being started.  To figure out why, you could check journalctl (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-journalctl-to-view-and-manipulate-systemd-logs) .  We can't see the code so we can't help you figure it out, but if you find an error message or panic in the logs, include it here

Comment: Thanks @erik258
I checked using journalctl -xfe -u 'goservice' and found an error with template execution.